# Why does bash sometimes forget the command typed previously?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, history

Came across a strange case on a Ubuntu Lucid system:

bash command line is working fine most of the time, but for some reason sometimes <kbd>Up</kbd> doesn't work to recall previous command. It remembers the previous ones but it's like the last one got forgotten. So it has to be typed or copy-pasted back in, really annoying...

Any idea what could be causing this ?

bash version is the one that came with the distro, 4.1.5(1)-release (package: 4.1-2ubuntu3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Commands entered with a leading space are typically not stored in bash's history.  This is a feature: if you want bash *not* to put a command in history, such as a dangerous command like `rm -rf ...`, place a space in front of it.  Also, duplicate commands may be ignored.

This behavior is configurable with the `HISTCONTROL` variable.  From `man bash`:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of values 
>   includes  ignorespace,  lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list.  A value of ignoredups causes lines
>   matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value  of 
>   erasedups causes  all  previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value
>   not
>                 in the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read by the shell  parser
>   are
>                 saved  on  the  history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound
>   command
>                 are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.

To see how your shell is configured, run:

```
echo $HISTCONTROL
```

To change to a new setting, edit your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Right on, `.bashrc` had `HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace`.

Comment: I did not know this! Thanks for the useful tip!